# TFS and Jenkins automation

Tags: jenkins, tfs

I am doing continious Integration between TFS and Jenkins.I am using TFS as a repository server.I am able to create workspace from TFS in jenkins and building of application successfully.I need automation build after TFS checkin.

Comment: Why not use TF Build? The new version in TFS 2015 has a node agent that runs on linux and mac

Answer (score 0):

IIRC Jenkins polls tfs to see if there's been a checkin, when there has it does a build (as opposed to TFS kicking off the build).

Comment: TFS 2013+ has the build agent polling for builds.